# Summation formulas for integral transforms other than the Fourier

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-list, integral-transforms, poisson-summation-formula

It seems to me that the Fourier transform harbours multiple useful results that allow one to sum an infinite series. The Poisson Summation Formula and Parseval's theorem. Also, Plancherel's theorem allows one to find the value of certain definite integrals.

These methods are all based on the Fourier transform. Yet it also appears to me that there are fewer theorems and results pertaining to infinite sums and integrals for other integral [transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), like the Abel transform, the Hermite transform, and the Laguerre transform.

> **Question**: are there also summation formulas for integral transforms other than the Fourier transform?

Comment: Parseval has an obvious analogue for Hermite and Laguerre or any decomposition into an orthogonal basis of some Hilbert space

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your comment, would you care to elaborate? Some examples would be great! Also, a friendly reminder that even though things may be obvious to you, they may not be to others

Answer (score 1):

The [Hermite transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_transform) says that the $ H_n$ form an orthogonal basis of $L^2(\Bbb{R},e^{-x^2})$ the Hilbert space with inner product $( f,g)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{g(x)}e^{-x^2}dx$ so that $$f =H_n \frac{( f,H_n)}{(H_n,H_n)}, \qquad (f,f)= \sum_n \frac{( f ,f)}{(H_n,H_n)} $$

This is similar to Parseval for the Fourier series where the $e^{2i\pi nx}$ form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$.

Parseval for the Fourier transform is a bit more general, it says that $f\to \mathcal{F}(f)$ is an unitary operator from $A=L^2(\Bbb{R})$ to $B= L^2(\Bbb{R})$, ie. $( f,f)_A=(\mathcal{F}(f),\mathcal{F}(f))_B$.

The Hermite transform is unitary from $L^2(\Bbb{R},e^{-x^2})$ to $\ell^2(\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0},(c_n))$ with $c_n=\frac1{(H_n,H_n)}$

Comment: Don't you mean $(f,f)= \sum_n \frac{\left|( f ,H_n)\right|^2}{(H_n,H_n)}$?